# How to solve for m in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve for $m$ in this equation, where $e$ is Euler's number, and $p,k,m \gt 0$, and $p \lt 1$?

$$p = \left(1 - e^{\frac{-kn}{m}}\right)^k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1 - e^{\frac{-kn}{m}} = \sqrt[k]{p} \Rightarrow e^{\frac{-kn}{m}} =1-\sqrt[k]{p} \Rightarrow \frac{-kn}{m}=\ln (1-\sqrt[k]{p}) \Rightarrow $$

$$m= \frac{-kn}{\ln (1-\sqrt[k]{p})}$$